# RHEL + what could be the root cause for very high await

Tags: linux, hard-drive, redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel

we have Kafka cluster servers  ( 11 Kafka servers )

each server is RHEL 7.6 with 32 cores (physical DELL server)

Kafka server include the OS - `dev253` disk and the Kafka disk - `dev8`

from `sar -d` we can see the following details

```
12:51:18 PM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
12:51:28 PM    dev8-0     11.90      0.00    215.10     18.08     12.62   1062.13     68.29     81.27
12:51:28 PM   dev8-16     74.10    708.00  27900.80    386.08    305.52   3590.92     13.50    100.01
12:51:28 PM  dev253-0      5.90      0.00    140.90     23.88      5.65    811.25     52.37     30.90
12:51:28 PM  dev253-1      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:51:28 PM  dev253-2      5.00      0.00     68.60     13.72      7.29   1635.48    132.50     66.25
12:51:28 PM  dev253-3      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

The high await persists throughout last 6 hours , and the same about disk %util

as I know await is a measure of how long a given IO spent in the entire IO scheduler. so if we  seeing hundreds of milliseconds here which is pretty bad.

so we want to know how to avoid this situation and I am wondering if the high util is related to following.

1. disk problem or disk health issue
2. kernel version is old and better to upgrade to latest kernel version. ( as RHEL 7.9 )

I also give here other details from memory point of view

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            376          46           1           4         328         323
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of command: `vmstat 1 5`?